# Java Error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.oreilly.servlet.multipart.MultipartParser

Tags: java, class, servlets, multipart

im kind of new at programming, so i really don't know how to make this work, i have some jsp files to upload some forms to a database, but when i try to send the form y get that exception.

I was googling it and i add some libs to the projects but it wont work, any help please ._.?

```
package res.ser.controlador;

import com.oreilly.servlet.multipart.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Hashtable;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import javazoom.upload.MultipartFormDataRequest;
import javazoom.upload.UploadBean;
import javazoom.upload.UploadFile;
import res.ms.sqlserver.SolRespaldo;
import res.ms.sqlserver.SolRestauracion;
import res.smtp.ForCorreo;

import com.smtp.AdmCorreo;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class SRSolicitud
 */
public class SRSolicitud extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * Default constructor. 
 */
public SRSolicitud() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int idUsuario = 0;
    try
    {
        idUsuario = ((com.bean.Usuario) request.getSession().getAttribute("usuario")).getIdUsuario();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {           
    }
    if (MultipartFormDataRequest.isMultipartFormData(request))
    {
        MultipartFormDataRequest mulForDatRequest = null;
        try 
        {
            mulForDatRequest = new MultipartFormDataRequest(request);
        } 
        catch (Exception exception) 
        {               
        }
        if (mulForDatRequest != null)
        {
            Hashtable archivos = mulForDatRequest.getFiles();
            UploadFile archivo = null;
            UploadBean upLoaBean = null;
            if ((archivos != null) && (!archivos.isEmpty()) )
            {
                archivo = (UploadFile) archivos.get("archivo");
                upLoaBean = new UploadBean();
            }
               try
               {
                    upLoaBean.setFolderstore(new com.utilidad.Utilidad().obtRutAplicacion()+"archivosTemporales/");
                    upLoaBean.store(mulForDatRequest, "archivo");
               }
               catch (Exception exception)
               {
               }
               String nomArchivo = null;
               try
               {
                   nomArchivo = archivo.getFileName();
               }
               catch (Exception ex)
               {                       
               }
               String tipSolicitud = null;
               try
               {
                   tipSolicitud = mulForDatRequest.getParameter("rTipo").toString();
               }
               catch (Exception exception)
               {            
               }
               if (tipSolicitud!=null)
               {
                   AdmCorreo admCorreo = new AdmCorreo(request);
                   String cueMensaje = null;
                   //String[] para={"efernandez@uv.mx"};
                   String[] para={"danigarcia@uv.mx"};
                   //String[] copCarbon={"oper_soptec@uv.mx"};
                   String[] copCarbon={"rmurrieta@uv.mx"};
                   String[] copCarOculta=null;
                   //para respaldos
                   if (tipSolicitud.equals("respaldo"))
                   {
                       String repeticion = null;
                       try
                       {
                           repeticion = mulForDatRequest.getParameter("rTRespaldo");
                       }
                       catch (Exception ex)
                       {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the class file of `com.oreilly.servlet.multipart.MultipartParser` in your **WEB-INF/lib** folder of your Container.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, no errors this time, i still can se the data on the database but thats another problem

Thank you!